# Why isn't from reportlab.graphics.shapes import string working

Tags: python-3.x, reportlab

Python 3.4 reportlab 3.2.0

```
from reportlab.graphics.shapes import string
```

Previously worked. Upgraded to newer Python and reportlab and it no longer works.

Was it replaced, eliminated, or moved?

Comment: Did you check the api docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [source](https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab/src/8fc7d11bdee07d84021cdfa92cd45c5ab032b8a8/src/reportlab/graphics/shapes.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#shapes.py-1383) on bitbucket the issue is simply that you should have capitalized `string` such that your import is as follows:

```
from reportlab.graphics.shapes import String
```

Which is the way it always should be done according to the `PEP 0008 -- Style Guide for Python Code`

> **Class Names**
>
> Class names should normally use the CapWords convention.
>
> The naming convention for functions may be used instead in cases where the interface is documented and used primarily as a callable.
>
> Note that there is a separate convention for builtin names: most builtin names are single words (or two words run together), with the CapWords convention used only for exception names and builtin constants.